# Using bind() to create a server with Lua Socket

Tags: lua, luasocket

Working with [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/home.html), this code works:

```
local socket = require'socket'
local server = socket.bind('*',51423)
local client = server:accept()
```

but this code fails:

```
local socket = require 'socket'
local server = socket.tcp()
server:bind('*',51423)
local client = server:accept()    
--> lua: /tmp/server.lua:4: calling 'accept' on bad self (tcp{server} expected, got userdata)
```

Yet the documentation for [TCP bind](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#bind) implies that the latter should work, stating:

> *"Note: The function socket.bind is available and is a shortcut for the creation of server sockets."*

How can I convert a generic "master" object into a server?

---

The motivation for this is the desire to add a timeout on the bind operation itself:

```
local socket = require'socket'
local server = socket.tcp()
server:settimeout(2/1000) -- Only wait 2ms when attempting to bind
server:bind('*',51423)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is at the top of the same documentation page (oops):

> *"A master object can be transformed into a server … with the method `listen` (after a call to `bind`)"*

It would seem that `s = socket.bind(…)` is actually equivalent to:

```
s = socket.tcp()
s:bind(…)
s:listen(32)
```

I'm not sure why they are split into two functions, but modifying the code to add `listen()` causes it to work:

```
local socket = require 'socket'
local server = socket.tcp()
server:bind('*',51423)
server:listen(32)
local client = server:accept()
```